# SASS Invalid CSS

Tags: css, sass, liferay, compass-sass

I'm trying to compile some `scss`  with compass but i get the error

```
error portal/forms.scss (Line 104: Invalid CSS after " width: ": 
expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "@model_hints_co...")
```

For the code:

```
.lfr-input-resource {
    width: @model_hints_constants_text_display_width@px;
}
```

The code comes from the liferay portal source code: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/b45e6646b18809abf13ddfb60d1d6566e22a8f8c/portal-web/docroot/html/css/portal/forms.css

And i don't know what `@model_hints_constants_text_display_width@px;` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this variable to your custom width value.

I've investigated it and I see that liferay has a function to replace this token to another value:

```
        public static String parseStaticTokens(String content) {
                return StringUtil.replace(
                        content,
                        new String[] {
                                "@model_hints_constants_text_display_height@",
                                "@model_hints_constants_text_display_width@",
                                "@model_hints_constants_textarea_display_height@",
                                "@model_hints_constants_textarea_display_width@"
                        },
                        new String[] {
                                ModelHintsConstants.TEXT_DISPLAY_HEIGHT,
                                ModelHintsConstants.TEXT_DISPLAY_WIDTH,
                                ModelHintsConstants.TEXTAREA_DISPLAY_HEIGHT,
                                ModelHintsConstants.TEXTAREA_DISPLAY_WIDTH
                        });
        }
```

For example, you shoud put 100px to the width:

```
.lfr-input-resource {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: I ended up replacing it with 350px since that´s what Liferay renders on my browser. I thought that it was a compass syntax that i didn´t understand.